# Get correct default(DateTime) in server

Tags: c#, date, datetime, asp.net-web-api, datetime-format

I obtain several parameters from the user, after some boilerplate code I obtain an URL like this:

```
http://localhost:58756/api/Shippers/GetShippers?page=1&date=1/1/01%2012:00:00%20AM&parx=y&and more parameters...
```

The part `date=1/1/01%2012:00:00%20AM` is obtained like this:

```
DateTime date=default(DateTime);
```

This gives `1/1/01 12:00:00 AM` that is `Jan 1st of year 0001`

I send the request and the method gets hit in the WebAPI service, but the date value is parsed like : `1/1/01 2001`

I know I can use `Nullable DateTime` or send the parameter as a formatted date `ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")`, etc.

But what about if I don't have control over what the client sends and I leave the DateTime parameter? how am I going to distinguish between 1st Jan 2001 and 1st Jan 0001 in the server?

Comment: If you have no control over what gets sent and what is received is `1/1/01 12:00:00 AM` then forget about how you are going to do it in code - how do *you* know that it means 0001 rather than 2001? Once you can determine what the logic that *you* use to determine the correct year then you should be able to put that in code. Or if not you can tell us the logic you use and we can help you put it in code. What *should* probably be happening is if you are being sent a two digit year then it should be specified what that means (eg it is a date in the range 2000-2099 or in the range 1970-2069...).

Comment: *I* certainly can't distinguish. You may have more info. And if not as I've just edited into the earlier comment the sender should be able to tell you what the date means. If they are sending ambiguous dates (eg because 0001 and 2001 are both valid) then that is a bug at their end that they need to sort out.

Comment: Perhaps my question could be: Is there a way to tell WebAPI: "Don't parse with that 2000's notation" ?

Comment: Don't use `DateTime`; just use `string` and manually parse it however you want.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yeah I know, I have that option and many more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing a two-digit year, .NET will use the [TwoDigitYearMax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax) property of the current culture's calendar.  By default, the Gregorian calendar used in most cultures will have a value of `2029`, which means that the 100 year range covered by two digits is from `1930` to `2029`.

You can change this by setting the current culture to a *custom* culture which has a different value for this property.

```
// clone the current calendar and change the range
Calendar cal = (Calendar) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.Clone();
cal.TwoDigitYearMax = 2099;  // changes the range to be 2000-2099 

// clone the culture, set the calendar, and make the new culture active
CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = cal;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;

// now all date parsing will use the new setting
```

There's a more detailed example of that in [the docs for the `yy` custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-yy-custom-format-specifier), which one would use if manually parsing from a string.  However, the same approach would be used when the parsing code was further up the stack.

As far as what to change it to - as Chris pointed out in comments, only you can determine that.

Answer (score 0):

If you get ony 2 digits for the Year, tehre is no way to figure out if they mean 1901, 2001, 9001 or 0001. That is **literally** the reason the Y2k Bug was a big thing [back in the day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem).

I have 3 basic rules for working with Datatimes:

1. Always store, retrieve and Transmit the UTC value. You do not want to add [timezones to your troubles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).
2. Avoid storage, retrieval or transmission as Text/string. If there is a proper datatype to use, use it.
3. In the case where you can not fulfill point 2, pick a fixed Culture Format and String Encoding at all Endpoints. You do not want to add that madness too your troubles.

Naturally the culture format should carry all digits of the year. Because otherwise we have issues like yours.